# How to save multiple selected checkboxes to a value in MVC4

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2008-r2

in my database I have these two tables (Project and Theme).

I also have a middle table called Project_Theme which contains ProjectID and Theme.

In Theme there are about 15 values pre-setted.

I am able to display all these themes into checkboxes however I don't know how to save them in my database.

Here is my controller :

```cs
private ProjectContext db = new ProjectContext();

    //
    // GET: /Project/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Project.OrderBy(i => i.Name).ToList());
    }

    //
    // GET: /Project/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {

        var model = new Project();

        ViewBag.Theme = db.Theme.ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
```

Here is my model :

```cs
public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

And my second model :

```cs
public class Theme
{
    [Key]
    public int ThemeID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Finally here is my create view :

```cs
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <div style="text-align:center;padding:0 1px 0 1px" >
        <table>
            <tr align="left">
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-label" style="width:110px">
                        <label for="theme">Theme(s)* : </label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @foreach (var t in theme)
                        {
                            <label class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="theme" value="@t.ThemeID"> @c.Name
                            </label>
                        }
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr align="left">
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-field focus">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { style = "width:410px" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

.........
```

So please if there is anyone that could help me, It would be really great :)

Comment: Can you provide more information about how you connect to your database? I'm assuming Entity Framework?

Comment: Web.config => connexion string System.Data.SqlClient which I affect in a DbContext => ProjectContext

Comment: So Entity framework then?

Comment: Couple of thoughts: Don't expose your Data Model ("Projects" table) as the ViewModel. You should have a "ProjectThemePicker" ViewModel that exposes just what you need to the View. Google for "MVC CheckBoxListFor" - this helps you convert a listing of objects into CheckBox choices.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to be glib or unhelpful, but this question has been answered on here many times (example - [MVC3 using CheckBox with a complex viewmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675037/mvc3-using-checkbox-with-a-complex-viewmodel)) and has also even been blogged about by Microsoft Gurus. It doesn't really warrant a full "example" answer on SO. My starting point would be, and honestly, I'm not being rude, to Google "mvc viewmodel checkbox list".

Essentially, you are trying to bend ASP.NET MVC to fit your ORM-generated relational database designed objects. Do it the other way round. Create a view model to help you do **what you need to do** which is to **get form data from a web page**. What you do once you've got that data is the important bit.

So even if you end up with an array of integers (eg theme IDs) in your POST action, you could still, at it's simplest level do this:

```
var newProject = new Project();

// set other properties from posted model first then...

newProject.Themes = model.ThemeIds.Select(x=> db.Themes.Find(x));
db.Projects.Add(newProject);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Hope that helps.